# Can super form Wordpress plugin works on different OS , with php version 7.0?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

Current PHP version for my dev server 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

My client is using redhat with php version 5.3

if ubuntu is changed to centos or red hat , functionality of php 7.0 and hence Wordpress plugin still consistent ?

I am talking about the plugin Super Form

Comment: I suggest trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.3 has different operator precedence to 7.x, if memory serves. So retaining the PHP version would be a problem. Plugins should work exactly the same between different OSes providing that permissions are the same. Changing between Apache and Nginx can break them if they're dependent on rewrites/.htaccess.

I hope that helps.